# Searching for the last instance of a header

Tags: excel, vba

I have a  of headers in a worksheet, all in row 1. I need to search through for the last instance of each particular header. Please see below a screenshot of a basic idea of what I am looking at. I would need the macro to identify either the last instance of "dog", reading from left to right, or the first instance of "dog" reading from right to left, either way returning the address of I1. The same applies for the rest of the headers, but I can handle that once given a functioning template.

I've checked around online, and I can't see anything that works.

[image: Headers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both solutions, the target column will be stored as a `Range` which will allow you to access properties such as `Range.Column`, `Range.Row`, `Range.Address`, etc. Both codes tested and working A-OK

---

### Loop Method

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LCol As Long, MyCell As Range, Found As Range

LCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each MyCell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, LCol))
    If MyCell = "Dog" Then
        Set Found = MyCell
    End If
Next MyCell

If Not Found is Nothing Then MsgBox Found.Address(False, False)

End Sub
```

---

### `Range.Find` Method

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LCol As Long, Found As Range

LCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set Found = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, LCol)).Find("Dog", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then MsgBox Found.Address(False, False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Formula Method

Approach without VBA using an array formula to return

- the column number:

  ```
  =MAX(IF(1:1="Dog",COLUMN(1:1)))
  ```
- or the address:

  ```
  =ADDRESS(1,MAX(IF(1:1="Dog",COLUMN(1:1))),4)
  ```

Both need to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> for Mac).